# Getting the .Find method to work in a method

Tags: c#, .net, string, list

I am trying to create a method that allows a user to enter a team, that name is then checked against  `List<string> teams`, if the team is there a message saying success and the teams name will appear.

The list with my fail .Find method-

```
 public FootballTeams(){ }

    List<string> teams;
    public void ListInit()
    {
        teams = new List<string>(10);
        teams.Add("Everton");
        teams.Add("Liverpool");
        teams.Add("Arsenal");
        teams.Add("Manchester United");
        teams.Add("West Ham United");
    }

    public void TeamSearch()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter the team you wish to search for: ");
        string userinput = Console.ReadLine();          
        string result = teams.Find(userinput);
        Console.WriteLine("Success, team " + result);
    }
```

The problem seems to be with `teams.Find(userinput);` as it has some invalid armaments?

Comment: It should be `Contains` not Find

Comment: @asawyer by replacing the .Find with Contains it comes up with the error that it can't convert type bool to string, is Contains for searching via the index?

Comment: @user2852418 Contains is to know whether the string exists in the list and returns a bool. Check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that will do the job for you is `Contains`

The code should be

```
public void TeamSearch()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter the team you wish to search for: ");
    string userinput = Console.ReadLine();          
    if (teams.Contains(userinput))
        Console.WriteLine("Success, team " + userinput);
}
```